# Call Angular's ng-show by Jquery but It is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I tried to set angularJs scope item from signalR method with Jquery but scope item doesn't change. Here is my code :

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/angular.js")

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
//Triggered from SignalR
        survey.client.refreshSurvey = function (connectionid) {
                var scope = angular.element($("#SurveyCtrl")).scope();
                scope.showGif = false;
                scope.$apply();

        };
    });
</script>
```

Html :

```
<div ng-app="SurveyApp" id="SurveyCtrl" ng-controller="SurveyCtrl">
  <div ng-show="showGif">
    <img src="image.gif">
  </div>
  <div ng-show="!showGif">
    <img src="backGround.png">
  </div>
```

I couldn't find where is it wrong ?

Comment: why don't you put your code inside angularjs controller ? you can check this project https://github.com/anik123/Chat-With-Angularjs-Signalr-Web-Api---Sql-server

Comment: Is it depend on inside angularjs controller ? Is this only solution? Is there any other solution here?

Comment: nope. it's may be didn't find from your controller. so instead of searching scope outside of controller better search use inside controller .

Comment: Thank u for your answer. I found solution. I know that is not best practise inline js but I try to focus call angular's func. Here is my solution :

var scope = angular.element($("#SurveyCtrl")).scope();
                scope.showGif = false;
                angular.element($("#SurveyCtrl")).scope().$apply();

Answer (score 0):

[**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/rKCqFy3VX7Oa3s9s8HtV?p=preview)

```
Hi,
```

Here I added sample for but invoke the function while button click it's working fine... you need this function for to accept jquery value set in angularjs..

```
   (function($, ng) {
        var $val = $.fn.val; // save original jQuery function
       // override jQuery function
      $.fn.val = function (value) {
        // if getter, just return original
        if (!arguments.length) {
          return $val.call(this);
        }
         // get result of original function
        var result = $val.call(this, value);
         // trigger angular input (this[0] is the DOM object)
        ng.element(this[0]).triggerHandler('input');
         // return the original result
        return result; 
      }
    })(window.jQuery, window.angular);
```

Comment: <div ng-show="!showGif"> for this in angularjs <div ng-hide="showGif"> is there same process